# Was Nimatron the first AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

As I understand it, the first true algorithmic intelligences were designed to engage humans in combinatorial [playgames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory#cite_note-5).

There is a patent for [Nimatron](https://www.google.com/patents/US2215544?dq=2,215,544&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn4bGzhbfTAhXMRiYKHWhVC04Q6AEIIzAA) filed by Westinghouse Electric in 1940, which was ultimately granted.  ([Edward Condon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Condon) is one of the inventors.)  It was also reportedly displayed at the [1940 World's Fair](http://www.goodeveca.net/nimrod/nimatron.html), and there is a [French Wikipedia article about it](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimatron).

However, this timeline of [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_artificial_intelligence) lists 1951 as the first working AI, again, notably, in reference to combinatorial playgames, in this case of the partisan variety.

There isn't a great deal of information about this on the web, so I wanted to put it before this Stack to get some clarity.

Also throwing uncertainty into the mix, the period between 1870 and 1910 is referred to as the ["The Golden Age of Automata"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaton#Modern) and I wonder if it's possible that a mechanical game AI might have existed, in the spirit of Babbage.

Comment: Sorry, could you spell out what you mean by "automata" and "artificial intelligence" more? Would the [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) be either? Would the [Jacquard loom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_loom)? Would the [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine)? What about [Heron's auto-theaters](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/periodictable/html/He.html) and [slot machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_machine#History)?

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for commenting!  I definitely wanted to get perspective on all of the links you presented.  I will clarify the question!

Comment: @Conifold Link "Heron's auto-theaters" to Heron in Erich Friedman's Periodic Table of Mathematicians is now https://erich-friedman.github.io/periodic/html/He.html